# Newsletter: Outlook and Images/Background-Images/VML-Images

Tags: image, email, outlook, newsletter, vml

I'm trying to display an image next to my 600px Content-Table on the left and right.
The image is 1px wide and 400px high and should be streched or tiled on the X-Axis.

Ofcourse it works with different approaches in all clients but Outlook 07/10/13.

My first approach was a background-image using various VML-Methods like v:rect, v:background or v:image which all did not work.

My latest approach is to simply use an img-Tag and use width:100%, width="100%" and even mso-width-percent:1000.

Sadly, none of the 100% methods seem to work in any Outlook later than 03.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image tag will work at 100%, but only if the image dimensions are larger than the 100%. Outlook doesn't stretch past the default image width, which in your case is only 1px.

VML should also work, try [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/)